# PHP array fixture list

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array...

```
$teams=array('team_one','team_two','team_three');
```

I am trying to create a (very basic) fixture list. The output I am looking for can be seen below...

```
team_one v team_two
team_one v team_three
team_two v team_one
team_two v team_three
team_three v team_one
team_three v team_two
```

The code I have, which obviously only works for the first team_one fixtures is...

```
$count=count($teams)-1;
for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
$opposition=$i+1;
echo "$teams[0] v $teams[$opposition] <br>";
}
```

The thing I can't get my head round is how to run through the loop again but now needing to start with team_two now, and being able to cycle back through the array so that team_one isn't missed out on the 2nd run, and team_one and team_two on the 3rd run.

If there is a better way of doing this (I'm sure there is) I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
foreach($teams AS $team) {
    foreach($teams AS $opposition) {
        if($team != $opposition) {
            echo "$team v $opposition <br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/i2HZo

Comment: easy as that, eh? Thanks very much, I was messing around with nested loops but couldn't get it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use tow for cycle:

```
$count = count($teams);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  for($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++) {
    if ($i == $j) continue;
    echo $teams[$i] . " vs ". $teams[$j] . "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: This returned many errors, one of which `Notice: Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' in /in/E2BHI on line 8` --- If you get a downvote, it would NOT have come from me; it's not my style. Did you test this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$teams=array('team_one','team_two','team_three');
$l = count($teams);

for($i=0;$i <$l;$i++){
$t2 = $teams[$i];
foreach($teams as $t){
  if($t != $t2 )
   echo $t ." VS ". $t2. "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: This is very similar to *jszobody*'s answer (except that this one uses a `for` loop instead of `foreach`)

Comment: actually i saw jszobody's code when i was submitting my code :)